# Flask closing flash message

Tags: javascript, html

I have flash message in my **Flask** app like this:
[image]

I want to if I click the close icon the flashed message is closing, or automatically closed in a set of time, eg: in 5 second it automatically closed.

Here is my **_flash.html**

```
{% macro render_flashes(class) %}
    {% with msgs = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=[class]) %}
        {% for msg in msgs %}
            <div class="ui {{ class }} message">
                <i class="close icon"></i>
                {{ msg }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endmacro %}

<div class="ui text container">
    <div class="flashes">
        {{ render_flashes('error') }}
        {{ render_flashes('warning') }}
        {{ render_flashes('info') }}
        {{ render_flashes('success') }}
    </div>
</div>
```

So what do I need to improve my code to do that..?

**PS**: for more information, I using this nicely [boilerplate](https://github.com/hack4impact/flask-base/blob/master/app/templates/partials/_flashes.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery. Add an onclick function to the button like so:

`<i class="close icon" onclick=delete_flash(this)></i>`

And here's the code to delete:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function delete_flash(flash){
        $(flash).parent().remove()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, can you also provide to autohide that flash message in a set of timeout..?

Comment: Try adding this after the delete_flash function:
 
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".{{ class }}").hide(500)
    }, 5000);
});